# Switch values between rows in unique column

Tags: hibernate, constraints, rdbms

Let's say you had a table like this:

```
id | name
---+---------
1  | foo
2  | bar
```

There is a uniqueness constraint on the `name` column.

How would you set the row with `id=2` to `foo`, and the row with `id=1` to `bar`?

I know you could probably just assign temporary names to both then stick in the desired names, but that does not seem like the simplest way.

I am using Hibernate, so any Hibernate-specific tricks would be nice. This seems like a problem that affects all RDBMSes in general though.

Comment: I can't help but wonder why you would need something like that, though. Are you trying to maintain some sort of ordered list? If so, you're better off adding a separate "element_index" column. Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 5):

In Sql Server you could update them both at the same time:

```
UPDATE table
SET Name = CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN 'bar' ELSE 'foo' END
WHERE ID IN ( 1, 2 )
```

Comment: +1, I didn't think this would work, but I tried it out (created a table, constraint, etc) and it does work

Answer (score 4):

In `SQL Server` and `Oracle`, constraints are deferred, that's why you just issue this query:

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     name = CASE name WHEN 'foo' THEN 'bar' ELSE 'foo' END
WHERE   name IN ('foo', 'bar')
```

As suggested in comments, it seems that you are using this in `MySQL` to maintain an ordered list (that was last time I encountered this problem).

In this case you may want to read the series of articles in my blog on how to do it in `MySQL` more efficiently:

- [**Sorting lists**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/25/sorting-lists/)

Comment: +1. Hibernate supports CASE statement in HQL: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions