# Postgresql updating values between two rows with unique constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am essentially asking the same questions as [Switch values between rows in unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246129/switch-values-between-rows-in-unique-column) but for PostgreSQL.

My situation is a bit more complex: I have a uniqueness constraint on several columns, let's say columns `a` and `b`. I want to exchange values in column `b` between rows, so for examples

```
id | a   | b
1  | "a" | 0
2  | "a" | 1
3  | "b" | 0
4  | "b" | 1
```

The desired result is,

```
id | a   | b
1  | "a" | 1
2  | "a" | 0
3  | "b" | 1
4  | "b" | 0
```

I have tried the following natural snippet of code: `UPDATE table SET b = CASE WHEN b=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END WHERE id <= 4;` (the WHERE part is something more complex in my case but it should change nothing).

What I get in the end is that the uniqueness constraint fails, and I don't have any ideas of what else to try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop a unique constraint on a column in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520005/how-to-drop-a-unique-constraint-on-a-column-in-postgres)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a deferrable constraint, e.g.:

```sql
create table my_table(
    id int primary key, 
    a text, 
    b int, 
    unique(a, b) deferrable);
```

Set the constraint to be deferred in the transaction:

```sql
begin;
set constraints all deferred;
update my_table set 
    b = case when b = 0 then 1 else 0 end 
where id <= 4;
commit;
```

Test it in [Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9624bf79f2c39a4f0c802553c958628e)

Read in the documentation: [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) and [SET CONSTRAINTS.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html)

Note, you can define the constraint as `deferrable initially deferred`, then you do not have to set the constraint before update.